# Kivy Python: confused with class and instance methods

Tags: python, oop, methods, kivy

I was trying kivy and while I was accessing class variables, I was forced to use 'self' for class variables or else it was producing error.

[image: .kv file code]

This is the kivy code I was using. Below is the main.py code where I have confusion:

[image: Code where confusion lies]

This code works. Here I am using class variables and accessing them from 'self'.

According to me the code that should work is:
[image: Code that should work]

OR

[image: Code that should work]

But both of these codes give error. What is it that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please post code as text, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kivy properties are Python [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), an object supporting a special api that let's them provide instance-level behaviour when accessed from a class instance.

I think you also have a misconception about class vs instance level variables: variables defined at class level are also accessible via instances of the class, it's normal that you can access `self.something_defined_at_class_level`.

Comment: Okay, got it. Actually my last two codes I pasted here were not working, that was the main problem. I know that instance namespace has class variables too [__dict__].